# I tried inner joining one table on another. It's joining side by side. Is there any alternative for inner join?

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema, ansi-sql

I have inner-joined two tables on 1 column. As per the method, it'll join side by side. For example

there are two tables
employee(id, date, department)
employee_1(id, date, department)

Let's take the employee data below

```
id   date         department
1    2022-09-09   professor
2    2022-10-08   professor
3    2022-10-11   professor
3    2022-09-02   professor
```

And employee_1 table is below

```
id   date         department
1    2021-09-09   professor
2    2021-10-08   professor
3    2021-10-11   professor
3    2021-09-02   professor
4    2021-09-10   professor
```

If I inner join the above two tables with the below query

```
select employee.*, employee_1.* from employee 
inner join employee_1
on employee.id = employee_.id
```

It'll return below table

```
id   date         department   date 
1    2022-09-09   professor   2022-09-09
2    2022-10-08   professor   2022-10-08
3    2022-10-11   professor   2022-10-11 
3    2022-09-02   professor   2021-09-02
```

How to get the output like

```
id       date         department
1    2022-09-09   professor  
2    2022-10-08   professor   
3    2022-10-11   professor   
3    2022-09-02   professor 
1    2021-09-09   professor
2    2021-10-08   professor
3    2021-10-11   professor
3    2021-09-02   professor
```

How to get the above table as output?

Comment: `select * from employee union all select * from employee_1`

Comment: [UNION](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/operators-query.html#union-all)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sql
select id, date, department
from employee
union all
select id, date, department
from employee_1
```